# Dynamics CRM 2015, Unable to connect to plugin registration tool SDK

Tags: dynamics-crm-2015

I am using **Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2015 online trial version**.
I got an error while trying to connect to plugin registration tool in the SDK 2015.

I am using windows seven 64-bit.

*The full stack trace message is this:*

```
Source  : mscorlib
Method  : HandleReturnMessage
Date    : 25/02/2015
Time    : 14:22:21
Error   : Une faute non sécurisée ou incorrectement sécurisée a été     reçue de l'autre partie. Voir le FaultException interne pour le code et les détails de la faute.
Stack Trace : Server stack trace: 
   à    System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.ProcessReply(Message reply, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState correlationState, TimeSpan timeout)
   à System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   à System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   à System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   à System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   à System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   à System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   à Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.IWSTrustContract.Issue(Message message)
   à Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustChannel.Issue(RequestSecurityToken rst, RequestSecurityTokenResponse& rstr)
   à Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceConfiguration`1.AuthenticateLiveIdInternal(ClientCredentials clientCredentials, SecurityTokenResponse deviceToken, String keyType)
   à Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceConfiguration`1.Authenticate(ClientCredentials clientCredentials, SecurityTokenResponse deviceTokenResponse, String keyType)
   à Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceConfiguration`1.Authenticate(ClientCredentials clientCredentials, SecurityTokenResponse deviceTokenResponse)
   à Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceConfiguration`1.AuthenticateLiveIdInternal(AuthenticationCredentials authenticationCredentials)
   à Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceConfiguration`1.Authenticate(AuthenticationCredentials authenticationCredentials)
   à Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmWebSvc.ClaimsIFDFailOverAuth[T](IServiceManagement`1 servicecfg, Uri homeRealm, ClientCredentials userCredentials, ClientCredentials deviceCredentials, Int32 depthLevel, Boolean tryNetworkCred)
   à Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmWebSvc.CreateAndAuthenticateProxy[T](IServiceManagement`1 servicecfg, Uri ServiceUri, Uri homeRealm, ClientCredentials userCredentials, ClientCredentials deviceCredentials, String LogString)
   à Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmWebSvc.DiscoverOrganizations(Uri discoveryServiceUri, Uri homeRealmUri, ClientCredentials clientCredentials, ClientCredentials deviceCredentials)
   à Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.CrmConnectControl.CrmConnectionManager.QueryLiveDiscoveryServer(ClientCredentials liveCreds, Uri discoServer)
   à Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.CrmConnectControl.CrmConnectionManager.FindCrmOnlineDiscoveryServer(ClientCredentials liveCreds)
       à Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.CrmConnectControl.CrmConnectionManager.ValidateServerConnection(CrmOrgByServer selectedOrg)


Inner Exception Level 1 : 
Source  : Not Provided
Method  : Not Provided
Date    : 25/02/2015
Time    : 14:22:21
Error   : Authentication Failure
Stack Trace : Not Provided
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is the obvious answer, but it looks like the credentials you provided may not be correct, or you are trying to connect to the wrong Online Region. I would try selecting "Don't Know" as the option for the Online Region, and try connecting again.

[image]

Comment: I already tried it, it's still doesn't work, thank you however.